# Android atom feed

Tags: java, android

Which is the best way to work with an atom feed in Android? Could somebody please point me to a free and easy to use library that has been proven to work with Android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the libraries you already found and deemed unfit in the Google search you did before asking this, so that we don't post the things you've already decided you don't want?

Comment: seems i was getting myself confused, sax will help me. the ibm urllouiscoquio posted was very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at this very complete article: [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @David, I removed it !